# Which Story was True Honey or Slave?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, prophet-muhammad

(First Story) - Sahih Muslim 1474 a

A'isha (Allah be pleased with her) narrated that Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) used to spend time with Zainab daughter of Jahsh and drank honey at her house. She ('A'isha further) said:
I and Hafsa agreed that one whom Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) would visit first should say: I notice that you have an odour of the Maghafir (gum of mimosa). He (the Holy Prophet) visited one of them and she said to him like this, whereupon he said: I have taken honey in the house of Zainab bint Jabsh and I will never do it again. It was at this (that the following verse was revealed): 'Why do you hold to be forbidden what Allah has made lawful for you... (up to). If you both ('A'isha and Hafsa) turn to Allah" up to:" And when the Prophet confided an information to one of his wives" (lxvi. 3). This refers to his saying: But I have taken honey.

(Second Story) - Sunan an-Nasa'i 3959

It was narrated from Anas, that the Messenger of Allah had a female slave with whom he had intercourse, but 'Aishah and Hafsah would not leave him alone until he said that she was forbidden for him. Then Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, revealed:
"O Prophet! Why do you forbid (for yourself) that which Allah has allowed to you.' until the end of the Verse.

Also in - Tafsīr al-Ṭabarī 66:1

The Prophet prohibits himself from being intimate with his concubine wife to please his other wives. In particular, it is alleged that Hafsa became upset when the Prophet was intimate with Maria the Copt in her house and on her bed, saying:

If both grade sahih then can you please tell which one is authentic? I’m confused

Comment: This was already asked in [Why two sahih hadith contradict each other related to qur"an 66:3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56812/why-two-sahih-hadiths-contradict-each-other-related-to-quran-663).

Comment: @Medi1Saif Should just close it as duplicate.

Comment: But, I suspect Harris really wants a polemic answer because people use the second hadith as if it shows the Prophet (SAW) was inappropriate or something. But, that's just an issue of mindset. It is the Prophet (SAW)'s right to be with his concubine, and that is entirely what the verses say. Why should he make something that is halal and good into haram just to please people?